# Keep Select2 open (Never collapse/allow size attribute)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-select2

Note: my examples are on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pk9fu6mn/).

I have a listbox as such:

```
<select id="plain" size="3">
  <option value="first">First</option>
  <option value="second">Second</option>
  <option value="third">Third</option>
  <option value="fourth">Fourth</option>
</select>
```

Note that the listbox shows 3 items on the screen immediately:

[image: example listbox]

I want to make this listbox more easily searchable, so I used Select2:

HTML:

```
<select id="fancy" size="3">
  <option value="first">First</option>
  <option value="second">Second</option>
  <option value="third">Third</option>
  <option value="fourth">Fourth</option>
</select>
```

JS:

```
$('#fancy').select2();
```

But the result is:

[image: example select2]

I would like `size="3"` to be honored, but I can't figure out how. There's `closeOnSelect: false` (from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26395096/jquery-select2-howto-make-dont-close-after-select)), but it still closes after double click. My Google searches are [not](https://www.google.nl/search?q=select2%20listbox) very [fruitful](https://www.google.nl/search?q=select2%20do%20not%20collapse).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like something that isn't part of the select2 library, but you can use some javascript for that:

```
var list = $("#fancy").select2({
  closeOnSelect: false
}).on("select2:closing", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
}).on("select2:closed", function(e) {
  list.select2("open");
});
list.select2("open");
```

Now the problem is that select2 don't really show only the 3 items you wanted (but all the 4). To fix that you can change the css (but you will have to say the exact height of the opened-menu):

```
.select2-container--default .select2-results > .select2-results__options {
    max-height: 90px
}
```

The `90px` is for your example. In different font-size/font-family/etc it might be different.

And to hide the selection arrow:

```
.select2-selection__arrow {
    display: none
}
```

Here is the update to your jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/pk9fu6mn/2/

Comment: This does exactly what I need, thank you. Might I add `.select2-selection__arrow { display: none }`? That will hide the down-arrow, which no longer has a function.

Comment: Yeah, I guessed you would want that :) You are welcome to update my answer and add it there if you want :)